# How to close an xml element using PHP DOM?

Tags: php, xml, dom

I've been using PHP DOM to create and save an xml file (third party xml file). So far i've got the structure right, but have come across the problem of an element not closing with a closing tag i.e.

```
<FX>
 <Stompbox ID="1">
  <Module ID="0" POS="0" BypassState="1"/>
 </Stompbox>
</FX>
```

Should look like this - Module closing tag

```
<FX>
 <Stompbox ID="1">
  <Module ID="0" POS="0" BypassState="1"></Module>
 </Stompbox>
</FX>
```

Here's the code

```
$xmlRoot = $domtree->appendChild($xmlRoot); 
    /* Add FX node */
$fx = $domtree->createElement("FX");
$fx = $xmlRoot->appendChild($fx);
    /* Add Stompbox node */
$fx->appendChild($stompbox = $domtree->createElement('Stompbox')); 

$attr_mod = new DOMAttr('ID', "1");
$stompbox->setAttributeNode($attr_mod);
$stompbox->appendChild($module = $domtree->createElement('Module'));

$attr_mod = new DOMAttr('ID', "0");
$module->setAttributeNode($attr_mod);
$attr_pos = new DOMAttr('POS', '0'); 
$module->setAttributeNode($attr_pos); 
$attr_bypass_state = new DOMAttr('BypassState', '1'); 
$module->setAttributeNode($attr_bypass_state);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The element is closed, it just happens to be a self-closing tag instead, notice the slash at the end `/>`

Comment: It is the proper way to close empty tags with the trailing `/>`: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-starttags

Comment: Thanks. The only reason i wanted the closing tag to be </Module> rather than just /> is because i don't want to break the third party formatting. Is there a way to be more specific and force the tag to be </Module> with PHP DOM?

Answer (score 2):

The element is closed. There are two ways of closing an element in XML:

by the self-closing:

```
 <someelement someattr="somevalue" />
```

Or with an empty innner:

```
 <someelement someattr="somevalue"></someelement>
```

They are semantically identical and many implementations choose for the former, because it results in smaller and more readable files.